# Implicit Casting

Tags: c#

I have a class `A` that inherits from `B`:

```
public class A : B { }
A a = new A();

List<B> list= new List<B> {
    a
}
```

This gives me an error saying that `a` cannot be implicitly cast to `B`.

When I try to cast `a` to `B`:

```
(B) a
```

Visual Studio says the cast is `redundant` and tells me to remove it.

Can someone please explain this?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: fixed and images added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error shows, the `MainMenu` in your code is referring not to your `MainMenu` class, but to `System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu`, which does not inherit from `UserControl`.

To remedy this, use a qualified namespace:

```
controls["MainMenu"] = new Assignment3.Views.MainMenu();
```

Or alternatively, you could use a different class name that doesn't conflict with a built-in class name.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have spent a long time trying to fix this, thought I was going crazy

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshots, looks like you are mixing the `System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu` class with your own `Assignment3.Views.MainMenu`.

Try this:

```
controls["MainMenu"] = new Assignment3.Views.MainMenu();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes

```
   public class B
    {
    }
    public class A : B
    {
        A a = new A();

        List<B> b = null;

        public A()
        {
            b = new List<B>() { a };
        }
    }
```